# Загрузка на android-смартфон файла из общей папки windows 7

Tags: android, samba

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь реализовать копирование файла из общей папки в память смартфона, выдает:

> could not execute method of the activity

при любых обращениях к  `SmbFile dir`, таких как, например, `int i=dir.getContentLength()`
Если убрать эту строку то ошибка возникает в `dir.copyTo(dest)`.

```
public class OpenFile {
    static void smb () throws IOException {
        String directory=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();           
        String urlToBackUpFile = "smb://LALKA1/NETWORK/test.txt";           
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, null, null);         
        SmbFile dir=new SmbFile(urlToBackUpFile, auth);     
        int i =dir.getContentLength();          
        File file=new File(directory+File.separator+"output.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {file.createNewFile();}
        SmbFile dest = new SmbFile (directory+File.separator+"output.txt");
        dir.copyTo(dest);
    }
}

public void clickButton (View view) throws IOException {
    OpenImage.smb();
}
```

При этом при попытке запустить тот же самый код с компьютера - все работает нормально:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String urlToBackUpFile = "smb://LALKA1/NETWORK/test.txt";
    System.out.println("Файл из которого берем инфу "+urlToBackUpFile);
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, null, null);

    SmbFile dir=new SmbFile(urlToBackUpFile, auth);
    System.out.println(dir.getDate());
    SmbFile dest = new SmbFile ("smb://192.168.1.104/NETWORK/test1.txt");
    System.out.println(dest.getDate());
    dir.copyTo(dest);

}
```

На всякий случай прикрепляю файл манифест

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

логи

```
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): Process: com.floorx.p_001_mapstore, PID: 1912
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     ... 11 more
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at jcifs.UniAddress.<clinit>(UniAddress.java:62)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getFirstAddress(SmbFile.java:864)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:954)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1338)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.length(SmbFile.java:2455)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getContentLength(SmbFile.java:2809)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at com.floorx.p_001_mapstore.OpenImage.smb(OpenImage.java:30)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at com.floorx.p_001_mapstore.MainActivity.clickButton(MainActivity.java:55)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     ... 14 more
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:365)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at jcifs.netbios.NbtAddress.<clinit>(NbtAddress.java:187)
05-06 06:40:43.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     ... 23 more
```

Comment: стактрейс ошибки??

Comment: @metalurgus добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это стандартная ошибка:

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Вы пытаетесь работать с сетью в основном потоке приложения. На **андроиде** так нельзя с определённой версии. Именно на андроиде и именно с определённой версии. На компе таких ограничений нет, засим код там работает.

Вам надо вынести работу с сетью в **отдельный поток**. Используя, например, **AsyncTask**.